# How do I transpose a List?

Tags: python, list, matrix, addition, transpose

Let's say I have a SINGLE list `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

How do I transpose them so they will be: `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]`?

Do I have to use the `zip` function? Is the `zip` function the easiest way?

```
def m_transpose(m):
    trans = zip(m)
    return trans
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`*splat`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) is the easiest way in pure Python.

```
>>> list_ = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> zip(*list_)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Note that you get tuples inside instead of lists.  If you need the lists, use `map(list, zip(*l))`.

If you're open to using `numpy` instead of a list of lists, then using the `.T` attribute is even easier:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> print(*a)
[1 2 3] [4 5 6]
>>> print(*a.T)
[1 4] [2 5] [3 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip()` doesn't seem to do what you wanted, using `zip()`  you get a `list` of `tuples`. This should work though:

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> old_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> for index in range(len(old_list[0])):
...     new_list.append([old_list[0][index], old_list[1][index]])
... 
>>> new_list
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with `None` as the first parameter:

```
>>> li=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> map(None, *li)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Unlike `zip` it works on uneven lists:

```
>>> li=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
>>> map(None, *li)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (None, 7)]
>>> zip(*li)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
#                      ^^ 7 missing...
```

Then call map again with `list` as the first parameter if you want the sub elements to be lists instead of tuples:

```
>>> map(list, map(None, *li))
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

(Note: the use of map with `None` to transpose a matrix is not supported in Python 3.x. Use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools to get the same functionality...)

Answer (score 1):

The exact way of use `zip()` and get what you want is:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*l)]
>>> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

This code use `list` keyword for casting the `tuples` returned by `zip` into `lists`.